# Feathersjs node socket client not connecting

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, raspberry-pi3, feathersjs

I have a feathersjs server running which I can connect to successfully from a browser client (using webpack).   Now I am trying to connect to same server from a nodejs app running on a Raspberry Pi3.    I see no activity of the server when I do a find.  I set up a hook logger for create on that service and it logs nothing.  I can only assume that the client is never connecting.  There is NO authentication hook on that service since I am just in dev so authentication module is not needed.

I can ping the server from the RPI and if I put the server ip/port into a browser on the RPI I get my "i'm a feathers server use a client" page so network connection and setup of IP on server is fine.

Any help on how to track down what is happening.  Without any connection log (on the client) I can't tell what is happening.  All I get is the timeout error from the .catch.

Below is my client code, the client code from the working browser client.

working browser client setup

```
import feathers from 'feathers'
import hooks from 'feathers-hooks'
import socketio from 'feathers-socketio'
import auth from 'feathers-authentication-client'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

// const socket = io('http://localhost:3030', {transports: ['websocket']})
// const socket = io('http://192.168.43.114:3030', {transports: ['websocket']})
const socket = io('http://192.168.0.51:3030', { transports: ['websocket'] })

const api = feathers()
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(socketio(socket))
```

//    .configure(auth({ storage: window.localStorage }))

```
export default api
```

not working nodejs client setup

```
const feathers = require('feathers/client');
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio/client');
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
// const errors = require('feathers-errors'); // An object with all of the custom error types.
// const auth = require('feathers-authentication-client');

const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');

const socket = io('http://192.168.0.51:3030', { transports: ['websocket'] })

const feathersClient = feathers()
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(socketio(socket))
//.configure(auth())

module.exports = feathersClient;
```

the node app which is just doing a find on my service.

```
const api = require('./api')

const switches = api.service('switches')

switches.find({
    paginate: false
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('loading all switch data', response.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error loading switch data', err)
    })
```

the error from the .catch

```
error loading switch data Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling switches::find
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/lighting-dev/node_modules/feathers-socket-commons/lib/client.js:87:25)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out The feathers docs for NPM/Node client are incorrect.
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html

the require

```
const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
```

is for browsers only

for nodejs use just base client

```
const io = require('socket.io-client);
```

and it works.